# How can I make a UIWebView load a webpage, but the URL is on a UILabel?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, encoding, uiwebview

How can I make an UIWebView load an webpage, but the URL is on a UILabel?I know its all about encodings,but how i'm using the following code!

```
NSString *urlAddress = //####### THIS SHOUL BE EQUAL TO MY LABEL URL #######//
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView loadRequest:requestObj];
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get property `text` of class `UILabel` to access its value:

```
UILabel *label;
NSString *urlAddress = label.text;
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView loadRequest:requestObj];
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply use `text` property?

```
NSString *urlAddress = [myLabel text];
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I don't understand, but assuming that your `UILabel` is `aLabel`, why not:

`NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[aLabel text]];`